# Install ubuntu 18.04 LTS while preserving Windows 10 OEM partition

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, oem

Is it possible (if so how) to format the SSD with Windows 10 installation to replace it with Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, while preserving a fully functional Windows 10 OEM partition? Goal is to have ubuntu os running on the primary SSD and having an option to recover to Windows 10 if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Windows 10 OEM partition may require specific settings in the boot loader to work. Also, the default Windows installer doesn't have the most rigorously capable formatting tool, and so may fail attempting to restore your Windows install in the future.

You have two better options than simply trying to "install around" the current recovery partition, options with a better chance of succeeding and less likelihood of being messed up by things you may accidentally do to your drive while working in Ubuntu.

The first option is to **create a full image backup** of a clean Windows install, including the boot partition and OEM recovery drive, and store that elsewhere where you can restore it.

The second option is to see if your computer has the option to **create a set of recovery media from the OEM recovery partition**. This option may be hidden and may require you to look for documentation on the process.

The benefits of both these methods are that you can restore back to your computer regardless of what happens in the meantime, what mistakes you may make while working with Linux, or even the HDD failing and you having to replace it.

Comment: I  believe, creating full image back up sounds as best option.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. All you have to do is create a bootable Ubuntuu 18.04 USB stick and boot install. Whilst installing you will be asked if you will like to keep your Windows 10 as a partition or remove it.